# Injecting javascript into an iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, scope

I am working with a page which includes an iframe containing a form.

I do not have access to modify the "source", but do have access to inject code via Google Tag Manager.

I was easily able to populate one of the form fields using:

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('my_iframe');
var iframeDocument = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
var amountInput = iframeDocument.getElementById("transaction_amount");
amountInput.setAttribute("value", "100");
```

However, I also want to change the `onclick` method for the form submission button, but am running into some issues. Initially I tried something like this:

```
function validate_form() {
  if (amountInput > 100) {
    alert("No chance!");
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
iframeDocument.getElementById("submit_button").setAttribute("onclick","return validate_form();");
```

I think the issues are a result of my "injection" being called from the main page, but the inject**ED** code being called from within the iframe. The first issue being that the submit button can't find the function...

To fix that I tried:

```
frames["my_iframe"].window.validate_form = function() { 
  if (amountInput > 100) {
    alert("No chance!");
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
iframeDocument.getElementById("submit_button").setAttribute("onclick","return validate_form();");
```

Now it fires, but can't access `amountInput`... again, suspect it is becasue it was defined in the scope of the main page, not inside the iframe.

I then fixed this by tweaking the original injection script to something like:

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('my_iframe');
var iframeDocument = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
var amountInput = iframeDocument.getElementById("transaction_amount");
amountInput.setAttribute("value", "100");
frames["giftCard_iframe"].window.amountInput = amountInput;
```

But all of this seems very messy and hard to follow. Is there a simpler/more standard approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually ended up taking a different approach with this.

Rather than injecting the script into the the iFrame, realised that I could reference the parent.function() from the iFrame.

This resolved the issues with not having access to the variables and the scope to call the function.

Answer (score 0):

You may use injected into the iframe script to do the same:

```js
var iframe = document.getElementById('my_iframe');
var iframeDocument = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;

var scriptSource = `
    window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        var form = document.getElementById('form'); // change to the actual form selector
        var input = document.getElementById('transaction_amount');
        input.value = 100;

        form.addEventListener('submit', function (ev) {
            if (Number(input.value) > 100) {
                alert('No chance');
                ev.preventDefault();
            }
        });
    });
`;
var script = iframeDocument.createElement("script");
var source = iframeDocument.createTextNode(scriptSource);
script.appendChild(source);
iframeDocument.body.appendChild(script);
```

I've added waiting for `DOMContentLoaded` event but if you're sure iframe's DOM is ready by the time you're going to inject this script you can omit the `addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ...)` wrapping.

Also I've changed `onclick` inline attribute with form's `submit` event listener. While you can submit a form multiple ways: hit `enter` when in one of the form's fields, tab-navigate to `submit` button and press `space` or `enter` on keyboard. The `submit` event is the final destination where you can validate the form before submission and prevent it if something went wrong. Ofcourse you'll have to assign some `id` or any other attribute to the form to be able to add event listener to it.

Comment: I wanted to avoid using a string.....do you have a slightly different way? Also it still seems super hacky and I had a gut feeling there must be a better approach

Comment: Instead of a string you may define this source as contents of `<script type="template/js">` tag. Type can be anything just not known javascript [mime](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types#textjavascript) type for it to not execute on your page immediatelly. Then you'll have to read contents of that tag and insert into iframe `script` element.